# How do you get the type of a variable in Ballerina?

Tags: wso2, ballerina

How do you get the type of a variable in Ballerina?

I know that boolean checks are possible such as these below:

```
import ballerina/io;

public function main() {
    any x = "This is a test";
    io:println(x is string); // Evaluates to true
    io:println(x is float); // Evaluates to false
}
```

In Python, we use `type(variable)` and get the type, in Java it is as follows:

```
String a = "test";
a.getClass().getName()
```

How do we do this in Ballerina? I've tried to look in the docs and the closest I can find is `lang.typedesc`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `typeof expression` for get the type of any variable in Ballerina.

```
import ballerina/io;

public function main() {
    var x = 5;
    io:println(typeof x);
}
```

Please refer to the "Typeof expression" section of the language specification below for more information.

https://ballerina.io/spec/lang/2019R3/#section_6.25